# explanation for the code snippet in C

Tags: c, int, operators, assignment-operator, postfix-operator

I came across this code snippet somewhere but cannot understand how does it works:

```
#include"stdio.h"

int main() {
  int j = 1;
  + j += + j += + j++;
  printf("%d",j);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
6
```

Please explain the working of this code snippet.

Comment: It's undefined behavior, so any explanation isn't generally useful.

Comment: I suggest you include "system" headers with the proper delimiters: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @pmg i haven't got what you said.

Comment: I'd say this wouldn't even compile, as `+j` isn't an lvalue.

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal, you have used `"` in `#include"stdio.h"` should be `"<stdio.h>"`

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: using quotes or angle brackets to delimit header names is different. The first is used for "user headers". the 2nd is used for "system headers". The include method is different according to the delimiters you use.

Comment: @alk this program compiled successfully on TurboC and the output is 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope you will understand if i write the same snippet other way explaining it

just note my point + variable is nothing but a positive variable and - variable is negative

now look at your snippet

```
#include"stdio.h"

int main() {
int j = 1;
+ j += + j++;// i.e "j+=j++;" which is "j=j+j; j= j+1;"
//now j = j+j "1+1" "j=2" and post increment then j=j+1 "2+1" "j=3"
+j+=+j;//which is j+=j or j=j+j
//hence j=3+3 i.e 6
printf("%d",j);//j=6
return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes. after posting this question I just tried the same thing with my compiler as well and it worked. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Your program will not compile as you are not providing an `lvalue` for assignment.

The following error message is shown by GCC,

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

In your program you have used short hand assignment operator,

For example consider the code,

```
a+=b;
```

means,

```
a=a+b;
```

But the way you used them is incorrect.

Comment: i have implemented this program on Turbo C++ and it worked perfectly there. I know the way of using unary operator is incorrect but its just a question I encountered somewhere.